# KMongo serialization of BSONTimestamp

Tags: jackson, kotlin

I m trying to serialize a BSONTimestamp with Kotlins KMongo lib. But within the MongoDb I only see its String representation.

```
"someVal" : {
    "inc" : 1,
    "time" : 1495104096
}
```

Do I need to put some Annotation for Jackson to serialize it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this has anything to do with KMongo actually but you can try reporting it to the github issues. The author is very responsive.

However, I read this as a Jackson serialization issue and so the best way to resolve that in my opinion would be to create a serialization rule similar to

```
object BSONTimestampModule : SimpleModule("BSONTimestampModule") {
    init {
        addSerializer(BSONTimestamp::class.java, object : JsonSerializer<BSONTimestamp>() {
            override fun serialize(value: BSONTimestamp?, gen: JsonGenerator, serializers: SerializerProvider?)
                    = gen.writeString(value?.time)
        })
    }
}
```

I don't know exactly what a BSONTimestamp is expected to save as so you may have to tweak it a bit but once the module is defined, register it with the Jackson Mapper like

`KMongoConfiguration.extendedJsonMapper.registerModule(BSONTimestampModule)`

Answer (score 0):

The anwser was quite simple, I used the wrong BSONTimestamp class.
For some reason there are two, one in *org.bson* and one in *org.bson.types*.
With the class from *org.bson* the KMongo build in Serializer does its job - duh!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are referring to the BsonTimestamp then which yes is the one mongo-java uses by default (and has nothing to do with KMongo actually). BSONTimestamp is a special implementation used "internally" to mongo and isn't normally suppose to be used by anyone external. Same is true for everything in the org.bson.types package. Those are not your normal contracts and are more for binary level or driver level interactions with mongo.

BsonTimestamp (in the org.bson package) is indeed the actual data type that you get back via any of mongos date transformations to/from.

Sorry I saw you use all uppercase BSON and assumed you meant to be doing something more advanced.